# Exit Survey popup with Volusion

Tags: volusion

I am using ResellerRatings for my exit survey popups on Volusion OrderFinished.asp.

ResellerRatings provided the following codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _rrES = {
    seller_id: 101069,
    email: "customer@home.com",
    invoice: "INVOICE NUMBER",
    auto: true
};
(function(w,o) {
    o=o||{};w.seller_id=o.seller_id||"";w.__rr_email_pass=o.email||"";w.__rr_inv=o.invoice||"";
    if(o.auto===false)w.__rr_autoEnroll=false;
    var s=document.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;
    s.src="https://www.resellerratings.com/popup/include/popup.js";var ss=document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    ss.parentNode.insertBefore(s,ss);
})(window, _rrES);
</script>
```

ResellerRatings instruction told me to "Please update the email: "customer@home.com" and invoice: "INVOICE NUMBER" values during implementation".

```
    email: "customer@home.com",
    invoice: "INVOICE NUMBER",
```

But I know these should be variables depending on each customer. I contact Volusion with an answer "no coding helps whatsoever...". So I would love to use Stackoverflow's power to help me out here. What are these variables should be and in what format? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
email: Order[9],
invoice: Order[0],
```

Comment: Thanks, will give you feedback when I test it out.